# Clear content from fields after save .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have aspx form with textboxes and gridview.
When i insert data to textbox it's shows on the gridview after clicking "Save".
I need to clear the content of fieds after i click on "Save".
I tried alot of things and searched in google but nothing works.
I am new at .net.. Can someone help please?
This is my save button fuction:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context1.sp_CreateUserTest(txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtMobile.Text,                DateTime.Parse(txtBirthdate.Text)); 
    grdvUsers.DataBind(); 
}
```

This is my pageLoad:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdvUsers.DataSource = Context1.sp_GetAllUserTest(); // select all users into gridview. datasorce = the data we want to dispaly.
    grdvUsers.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: "I tried alot of things and searched in google but nothing works" so what have you tried and in what way didn't it work?

Comment: I tried this: foreach (var item in Page.Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)item).Text = "";
            }
        } 

and this: foreach ( Control ctl in Parent.Controls) {
 if (ctl.GetTyep()== TextBox)
        ctl.text = ""; 
 } 

and more.. but it does not respond.. still showing content after saving

Comment: Have you tried clearing the field by setting the text property at the end of your save function?  e.g. txtName.Text = string.Empty

Comment: When i do txtName.Text = string.Empty its working but i want to do it to more than one field, and maybe fields will be added in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Simply make a method for clearing the controls that you want to clear:

```
private void ClearControls()
{
 txtName.Text =""; // resetting textbox
 txtEmail.Tex="";
 txtMobile.Text ="";
 ddlSomeDropDown.SelectedIndex = -1; // reset dropdown
 somecheckBox.Checked = false;  // reset checkbox
 someRadio.Checked = false;   // reset radio
 ..................
 .................
 // more controls here
}
```

and call it after saving :

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context1.sp_CreateUserTest(txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtMobile.Text,                DateTime.Parse(txtBirthdate.Text)); 
    grdvUsers.DataBind();
    ClearControls();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign text fields a empty string.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context1.sp_CreateUserTest(txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtMobile.Text, DateTime.Parse(txtBirthdate.Text)); 

 txtName.Text = String.Empty;
 txtEmail.Text= String.Empty;
 txtMobile.Text= String.Empty;
 txtBirthdate.Text= String.Empty;

    grdvUsers.DataBind(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this.

You can clear date and datepicker with `DatetimePicker1.Clear();` or with the provided ID